# r: Inserting ggtexttable() inside a ggplot graph

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to insert a table that I created using the ggtexttable() function from the ggpubr package inside the plotting boundary of my ggplot plot. However, I keep getting this error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class "c("gg", "ggplot")" to a data.frame
```

I don't understand why I am getting error but I have a feeling it has to do with that I have dates on my x-axis? I would appreciate any feedback to fix this issue! Thanks!

**Data:**

```
HUC_df1 <- structure(list(charnam = c("Total dissolved solids", "Total dissolved solids", 
"Total dissolved solids"), stdate = structure(c(11297, 11296, 
11298), class = "Date"), val = c(439, 437, 510), HUC14 = c("HUC02030104020030", 
"HUC02030104020030", "HUC02030104020030")), .Names = c("charnam", 
"stdate", "val", "HUC14"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
HUC1_count<-structure(list(year = "2000", n_greater = 1L, percentage = 33.33, 
    n = 3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), .Names = c("year", "n_greater", "percentage", "n"))
```

**Code:**

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot2)

theme_graphs<- theme_linedraw()+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",vjust=0.5,hjust = 0.5),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        plot.background = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.5, 0.2),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text=element_text(size=10, face="bold"))
HUC1_table<-ggtexttable(HUC1_count, 
                     theme = ttheme("classic"),rows=NULL,
                     cols=c("Year","Number of Samples\n>500",
                            "Percent of Samples\n>500","Total Samples"))
HUC1<-ggplot(data = HUC_df1, aes(x =stdate, y = val)) +
  geom_point()+
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 500,color="red"),size=1.3)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 700))+
  scale_x_date(date_labels ="%b%Y")+
  ggtitle("Elizabeth R (below Elizabeth CORP BDY) (HUC02030104020030)\nTDS Concentration (mg/L);1997-2018") +
  xlab("Year") + ylab(" TDS Concentration (mg/L)")+
  scale_color_manual("",
                     values = c("red"),
                     labels=c("Freshwater Aquatic Life Criteria for TDS = 500 mg/L"))+

  theme_graphs+
  theme(legend.position =c(0.5, -0.098))


  HUC1<-HUC1+annotation_custom(tableGrob(HUC1_table), xmin=1.5, 
                               xmax=1.8,
                               ymin=200, ymax=300)
```

Comment: What is the content of `HUC1_count`? What where does `theme_graphs`? When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry. Just updated question.

Comment: In the future, it would be better just to drop any lines of code that aren't directly related to the problem. Just get rid of all the extra lines of theme and customizing labels. That's just extra code to sort through that's not directly related to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems here. First, `tableGrob` is a function for creating a grob from a data.frame. But you've already created your table do you don't need that function. But `ggtexttable` returns a ggplot object, but you need a grob, so you need ot use `ggplotGrob` to turn that ggplot object into something you can use with `annotation_custom`.

The second problem is the range you specific for your x values. Since your data is formatted as a Date vector, those values are stored as the number of days since 1970-01-01 so values of 1.5 and 1.8 are way outside the range of what you are actually plotting. You can see your actual range with

```
range(as.numeric((HUC_df1$stdate)))
# [1] 11296 11298
```

So fixing those two problems, what you want for the example is

```
HUC1+annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(HUC1_table), xmin=11296, 
                                xmax=11298,
                                ymin=200, ymax=300)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for the inconvience young king!